# Ordenar datos, Biometrico

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Tengo un biometrico, el cual es muy sensible y tengo un problema al momento de calcular sus horas laboradas, al momento de correr mi macro le hago que me ordene de 4 en 4, solo quisiera que me ordene los valores que no están pintados de color amarillo...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> El orden que necesito es el siguiente 
>   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo !!!

```
    For a = 0 To 240
    'MsgBox "Contado de columna total: " & a

        contini = contador

        For b = 1 To 4
        contador = contador + 1
        valorinternos = Range("A" & contador).Value

        Next

        celdainicio = "M" & contini + 1
        celdafin = "M" & contador

        Worksheets("24_25sep").Range(celdainicio & ":" & celdafin).Copy _

        Range("E" & a * 4 + 1).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True

   Next a
```

Comment: donde esta tu macro? como es? entiendo que esos datos son exactamente el mismo, pero no deberias depurarlos antes de tratar de ordenarlos?

Comment: Como los podria depurar?? me podrias ayudar

Comment: Y deberias verificar tus datos y si encontras dos seguidos con el mismo estado en un rango de tiempo capaz borrar uno? No sabria como queres q te ayudemos

Comment: Lo entiendo, soy principiante en esto, me explicar un poco mas , para saber como borro un dato de ellos

Comment: Usa el botom [edit] y agrega la informacion a la pregunta. Tambien por favor hace el [tour] y mira [ask]

Comment: Listo gracias!!

Comment: Deberías primero hacer un bucle en la columna TIEMPO. Si el color de la celda es amarillo, entonces borra la fila entera, porque no la necesitas para tus datos, según lo que has contado de omitir las amarillas. Es fácil detectar el color de la celda con VBA **siempre y cuando ese amarillo no provenga de una regla de formato condicional**. Algo tipo `If Range("D1").Interior.Color=Vbyellow Then ` debería permitirte distinguir entre amarillas y no amarillas.